# Import WordPress, Failed to import sizes

Tags: media, import

Have an odd problem trying to use wordpress importer.

Export posts from live site, try to import to new site but no media is imported.

I just get this-

```
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes small
Failed to import sizes small
Failed to import sizes medium
Failed to import sizes small
Failed to import sizes large
...for a few hundred lines
```

No other errors seen or in PHP log.

Comment: Does your media are accessible by url to site where you want to import them?

Comment: yep its a live site.

Answer (score 1):

Add `define('IMPORT_DEBUG', true);` to your `wp-config.php` to display errors.

Comment: done and still no errors

Comment: Can you send me sample xml file with couple of posts and couple of media images e.g. to https://wetransfer.com/ or paste xml file content to your question?